# Looping over child selectors

Tags: jquery

greetings,
I have a div wrapped around a bunch of checkboxes on my form.

```
<div id="checker">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dynamic" id="dynamic" value="dynamic" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dynamic" id="dynamic" value="dynamic" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="dynamic" id="dynamic" value="dynamic" />
</div>
```

... where "dynamic" (above) is coming from a database and I don't know the names or ids.  These would be created in a loop of php code - not shown.

Using JQuery, how do I access these checkboxes, so I can loop over them?  I'd like to do something like:

```
$('#checker').children('checkbox').each( function(){ .... });
```

(I know that is wrong - it's just to show what I'm thinking).

Thoughts?  Thanks
JohnC

Comment: Hmmm!  My post seems to have removed my div example and check boxes. My checkboxes are coming from a database and I do not know their names, ids or values.  I only know they are checkboxes inside a div tag with an id="checker"

Comment: Highlight the code and press ctrl-k or click the "code" button on the editor toolbar (looks like 0101010).  That will format it for display.  Bingo!

Comment: Clicking on the `code` button in the editor, or indenting all your code by 4 spaces will cause the code to be displayed :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#checker input:checkbox').each( function() { ... } );
```

Comment: Oh, nifty.  I didn't know about the implicit "all elements" in the :checkbox selector.  Good call.  I'm upvoting yours.

Comment: Yes, it is there, but for performance reasons you should put a tag name before it, because then jQuery can use the getElementsByTagName function and does not need to check *every* element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#checker input:checkbox').each(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: For performance you should use a tag name (input:checkbox) because then jQuery can use the getElementsByTagName function and does not need to check *every* element.

Comment: @AndreKR thanks! This is most definitely correct, as stated in the jQuery documentation for ':checkbox' http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 1):

$('#checker input:type="checkbox"').each(...);

Comment: close...  $('#checker input[type="checkbox"]').each(...);

Answer (score 0):

If #checker is the id to your div then

```
$("div#checker input:checkbox").each(function () { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checker').children('input [type="checkbox"]').each(
  function(){ 
    .... 
  });
```